# Move a directory that contains an execuitng script

Tags: bash, mv

I have a bash script that does except some actions the following:

```
mv "$currentDir" "$currentDir@backup"
mv "$tempBuild" "$currentDir"
```

I run my script by doing two steps:

```
cd /path/to/project
./my_script.sh
```

I expected that ***$currentDir*** should always be equated to ***/path/to/project***.
But when I run it second time by adding the 3rd step ***./my_script.sh*** the current directory value becomes ***/path/to/project@backup***.
What am I doing wrong, is it possible to improve the script for doing that stuff or should I change an approach?

Also I'm getting the current directory by this way:

```
currentScriptAbsolutePath=$(cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` && pwd)/`basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`
currentDirAbsolutePath=$(dirname $currentScriptAbsolutePath)
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post your script or, at least, a simplified one which can be used to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my toolbox I have this to get the script path and the caller path.
This can help you

```
# Set path
CALLER_PWD=$(pwd)
case "$0" in
    */*)
        SCRIPT_PWD=`dirname "$0"`
    ;;
    *)
        SCRIPT_PWD=`/bin/which "$0" | head -1`
        SCRIPT_PWD=`dirname "$SCRIPT_PWD"`
    ;;
esac

cd "$SCRIPT_PWD"
SCRIPT_PWD=$(pwd)
cd "$CALLER_PWD"
```